# Active Record find missing many to many

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

Given the two following models:

```
class Scientist < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :papers
end

class Paper < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :scientists
end
```

So each scientist has many papers and each paper has many scientists (authors so to speak). My goal is to find all scientists who don't have any papers associated with them.

```
Scientist.left_joins(:papers).where(papers: {id: nil}).pluck(:name)
```

This raises the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing
>   FROM-clause entry for table "papers"

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Ruby 2.6.5 with Rails 6

Comment: I think the error is somewhere else. The above example should work perfectly well.

Comment: Update your question with full backtrace errors? are you sure you ran all migrations? post schema.rb ?

Comment: @ndnenkov all tables involved have a table_prefix (`my_app`). The join table is called `my_app_scientists_papers`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Severin I think it might be. The where statement needs the table name

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery How would you provide the name of the join table for the above query?

Comment: @Severin `Scientist.left_joins(:my_app_scientists_papers).where(my_app_scientists_papers: {id: nil}).pluck(:name)` if that's the joins table. I'm not 100% familiar with habtm. I use has many and has many through

Comment: Sorry, @Severin `Scientist.left_joins(:my_app_scientists_papers).where(my_app_scientists_papers: {paper_id: nil}).pluck(:name)` like i said i don't use habtm

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery it can't find the association when doing it like that, so the original join already worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209466/discussion-between-severin-and-intl-man-of-coding-mystery).

Answer (score 1):

The query you are looking is (assuming the migration is correctly created and the table relating both models is called `scientists_papers`):

```
Scientist.includes(:scientists_papers).where(scientists_papers: {scientist_id: nil})
```

which generates an SQL query like:

```
SELECT "scientists".* FROM "scientists" LEFT OUTER JOIN "scientists_papers" ON "scientists_papers"."scientists_id" = "scientists"."id" WHERE "scientists_papers"."scientists_id" IS NULL
```

As you are using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation, there is no reference to `papers` from the `scientists` table (so you can not do `left_joins(:papers)`). The relation looks like:

[image]

Check [Rails documentation about the has_and_belongs_to_many Association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) for more details.